# How can i create an user with system administrator profile when seeAlldata = false in a test class

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I want to create an User in test class with system Administrator profile.

The issue which i have is that i have seeAllData = false where in the test class would only use data from within the test class.

```
 List<Profile> ps = [select id, name from Profile where  name = 'System Administrator'];
```

This might not return any values.

Any ideas how we can create an user

**EDIT**

I can get the data for the query on even with seeAllData= false. So is it that Profile records are visible even if SeeAllData = false ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm), the User and Profile objects are considered "objects that are used to manage your organization" and can be accessed regardless of whether or not your test class/method includes the `IsTest(SeeAllData=true)` annotation.

Other objects that are accessible in this manner include:

- Organization
- RecordType
- ApexClass
- ApexTrigger
- ApexComponent
- ApexPage

Answer (score 0):

```
We can use the code directly to create a role and attach it to a user with system admin profile.

@isTest static void UserCreate() { 
UserRole obj=new UserRole(Name= 'ABC'); 
insert obj; 

Profile pf= [Select Id from profile where Name='System Administrator']; 

String orgId=UserInfo.getOrganizationId(); 
String dateString=String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','') 

Integer RandomId=Integer.valueOf(Math.rint(Math.random()*1000000)); 
String uniqueName=orgId+dateString+RandomId; 

User uu=new User(firstname = 'Alan', 
lastName = 'McCarthy', 
email = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org', 
Username = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org', 
EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1', 
Alias = uniqueName.substring(18, 23), 
TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', 
LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', 
ProfileId = pf.Id, 
UserRoleId = obj.Id); 

}
```